# XSLT Transformation help on inner elements

Tags: xslt

```
<name> ABC     <suffix>XYZ</suffix> </name>
```

How to transform name element without suffix and just suffix separately any help greatly appreciated, I tried child,ancestor with not option but didn't work

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the expected output of the transformation in your example?

Comment: expected output is <product_name> ABC </product_name> <product_suffix> XYZ </product_suffix>

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<xsl:template match="name">
    <product_name>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
    </product_name> 
    <product_suffix>
        <xsl:value-of select="suffix" />
    </product_suffix> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, I tried that but for some reason the output I see is not the expected  ' <product_name> ABCXYZ </product_name>   <product_suffix> XYZ  </product_suffix> '

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution I got was to not include inner element using

```
/node()[not(self::suffix)]
```

Thanks for your help